# Chart.js pie tooltip getting cut

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js pie chart with tooltips which being cut for some reason.

Screenshot attached, didn't found any attribute/option to take care of it..

Is there anyway to take care of it?[image: Tooltip being cut]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you adding this chart in some div? if yes then maybe increase width of that div, might helps

Comment: I don't have enough space to increase width.. There's no way to get the tooltips inside the pie?

Comment: Is there any way you can control tooltip direction?

Comment: If I had any clue how do that I wouldn't come here ;)

Comment: Post your graph code to jsfiddle and we might be able to give you some help from there.

Comment: I added a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54301153/5330805

Comment: Your best bet is to render tooltips with custom HTML.  See an official example here.  It works just fine.  https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-pie.html

Comment: You can look at my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205306/3190576) to an identical question which provides a code for external tooltips.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This improper cutoff was raised as issue#622 in the Github repository for ChartJS.

**This was determined to be a bug (evidently this bug hasn't yet been fixed)**

https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/622

In response to that issue, Robert Turrall has a solution which he says is a good workaround. Here is his proposed fix:

> I'm sure that this is due to the fact that the tooltips are generated
>   within the confines of the canvas, making it difficult to fix.
>
> I had the same issue on my doughnut chart and solved it by
>   implementing custom tooltips as per the example on the samples folder
>   - worked in conjunction with my existing tooltip fontsize and template settings in the chart initialisation code:
>
> ```
> var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(donut).Doughnut(donutdata, {
>   tooltipFontSize: 10,
>   tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>hrs",
>   percentageInnerCutout : 70
> });
> ```
>
> Check out samples/pie-customTooltips.html for the custom tooltip code.
>   Copy/paste and it worked straight away. Very happy!
>
> Tooltip displayed well outside the bounds of the canvas:
>
> PS: there's a line chart example too, which I'm guessing will work
>   fine with bar charts.

Comment: Chart.js docs already provide a workaround with external tooltips. You can look at my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205306/3190576) to an identical question which provides a code for external tooltips.

Answer (score 4):

You can add internal padding to the chart. For instance in my case I had a cut of tooltips on the right.

```
                    options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    cutoutPercentage: 60,
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    animation: {
                        animateRotate: false
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            right: 40
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: layout padding helped.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for this.  I have blank labels on my x axis, so I just added a label with several spaces in it for the last label entry.  That caused ChartJS to leave enough space for the label to fit, which also leaves enough room for the tooltip to fit.

In addition, I have large circles for my data points and the last one on the right was getting clipped before.  Adding the extra space to the label also fixed that.

Here is the code where I create my labels.  The `ratings` is my actual data defined earlier:

```
// Add blank labels and "Today"
for (i=0; i<ratings.length; i++) {
  labels.push("");
}
labels[ratings.length-1] = "       ";

var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
      {
          label: "Progress",
          strokeColor: "rgba(255,165,0,1.0)",
          pointColor: "white",
          pointStrokeColor: "rgba(255,165,0,1.0)",
          pointHighlightStroke: "#B87700",
          data: ratings
      }
  ]
};
```

Even if you have actual labels on your graph, you could add spaces to your last label to make it bigger.  If you are centering your label, you could add the same amount of space before and after.

Obviously there will be limits where this will or won't work for you, but for my case I added 7 spaces and all looks good now.

Also, my case had an issue on the right side, whereas this question has an issue with the left side.  The same fix should work, but putting the space on the first label.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Chart.js can't figure out which direction to show the tooltip because it can't detect the size of the tooltip element when it extends **beyond** the canvas.

In my scenario I fixed it by squeezing the text inside this particular tooltip closer with these options for the tooltip options object:

```
        tooltips.titleMarginBottom = 1;
        tooltips.bodySpacing = 1;
        tooltips.yPadding = 2;
```

Wierdly enough Chart.js then correctly decides to show the tooltip to the left of the mouse and not below.
Would be cool if you could choose which direction the tooltip appears compared to the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to work around this issue by reducing the amount of text in the tooltip. I did so using custom tooltip callbacks to specify the label text. My initialization looked like this:

```js
var chart = new Chart(canvas.getContext("2d"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return tooltipItems[0].xLabel;
                },
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return tooltipItems.yLabel;
                },
            }
        },
    },
});
```

There appears to be a fix available that hasn't yet been merged into the project: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/1064

Answer (score -2):

Interestingly, by the setting the `tooltipCaretSize` option to `0` solves the issue.
`{ tooltipCaretSize: 0, ... }`