# chartjs tooltip is cut off when out of canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm currently using chartjs ([chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/)).

Tooltip is cutted, because it go out of canvas.
How I can fix this behavior?

[image: chart-with-legend-cuttedoff]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple ways of solving this.

One way *(in your case)*, you can solve this, is by setting the bottom padding for your chart layout , like so ...

```
options: {
   layout: {
      padding: {
         bottom: 25  //set that fits the best
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Standard Rating',
         data: [0.1, 0.02, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(209, 230, 245, 0.5)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(56, 163, 236, 1)',
         borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
   options: {
      layout: {
         padding: {
            bottom: 25  //set that fits the best
         }
      },
      responsive: false,
      tooltips: {
         yAlign: 'top'
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in your solution if chart have lower value I have the same issue.

Comment: try to set data array like this: `data: [0.1, 0.02, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: then, just increase the padding value. see updated answer.

Comment: it doesn't resolve the issue in my case, but I'll accept this answer

Comment: hm.. there are other ways, you can check [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3A%20tooltip%20cut%20off%20)

Comment: I'm thinking this should be a chartjs issue/feature.  It should detect it has alot more real estate on top of the point, so the tooltip should be rendered above.  (of course) unless you have the tooltip fixed to render below.

Comment: Sadly, this solution makes my chart almost invisible. You can look at my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205306/3190576) which provides a code for external tooltips.

Answer (score 10):

You can use external tooltips option. Here's an example from Chart.js [tooltips](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips) documentation:

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
        enabled: false,

        custom: function(tooltipModel) {
            // Tooltip Element
            var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

            // Create element on first render
            if (!tooltipEl) {
                tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                tooltipEl.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                tooltipEl.style.borderColor = "#000000";
                tooltipEl.style.borderWidth = "thin";
                tooltipEl.style.borderStyle = "solid";
                document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
            }

            // Hide if no tooltip
            if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                return;
            }

            // Set caret Position
            tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
            if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
            } else {
                tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
            }

            function getBody(bodyItem) {
                return bodyItem.lines;
            }

            // Set Text
            if (tooltipModel.body) {
                var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                    innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                    var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                    var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                    style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                    style += '; border-width: 2px';
                    var span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
                    innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
            }

            // `this` will be the overall tooltip
            var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            // Display, position, and set styles for font
            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
            tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
            tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
            tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
            tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the tooltips position property to nearest.

```
tooltips : {
    position: "nearest"
},
...
```